# result of arithmetic operation like: 1/3 in C float variable

Tags: c++, c

I am writing simple program where I am doing operation like 1/3, 1/5 .
But while printing o/p it prints 0.00 ..

```
int main()
{
 float res = 0.0;
 int no1 =1 ;
 int no2 = 3;

 res = (no1) / (no2) ;

 printf("Res:[%f] ",res);

 }
```

~

ideally it should print 0.3 but it prints 0.0000.

Comment: Because 1/3 on integer variables gives integer arithmetic, not float. There are thousands upon thousands of duplicates to this question, and your C book would tell you the answer as well.

Comment: Integer division will result in an integer, you could make one of the operands a float `res = no1 / (float)no2;`

Comment: That's because you are dividing integers. If you use float for the numbers you'll get the expected result.

Comment: You mention _one_ language in the title, but tagged it with two.  You are either using C or C++ compilation - ask and tag the question in relation to just the one you are using, lest you get an answer that is specific to the one you are not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no1 and no2 have int type. It means that results of any operations also int. 
So 1/3 is 0 (int) and then 0 casts to float

Solution. Make no1 or no2 or both floating point. For example:

```
res = (float) no1 / no2;
```

or

```
float no1 = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Given that it is tagged both C and C++, an answer that would work in either might be more appropriate.  The title specifis C, and this is C++.